# Why is this MGF identity true?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normal-distribution, moment-generating-function, sum

If $X_i \overset{i.i.d.}\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2) $, we know that: $\bar{X} \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2 /n)$.

But why does:
$$\exp\left({\sigma^{2}\over 2}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(t_{i}-\bar{t})^{2}\right)= M_{X_{1}-\bar{X},X_{2}-\bar{X},...,X_{n}-\bar{X}}(t_1,t_2,...,t_n)$$
Where $M$ is the moment generating function?

I have three pages of scratch work but it would be incredibly tedious to post that here, and I already know it's true ...

Answer (score 2):

I will not write this out in detail, but give the main ideas. It becomes easier if you use the multivariate normal distribution.  Write $X=(X_1, \dots, X_n)^T$ the data in vector form, and $\bar{X}$ for the arithmetic mean.  Then the $(n-1)$-vector $(X^T, \bar{X})^T$ (in block form) has a multivariate normal distribution of dimension $n+1$, but with a singular covariance matrix (of rank $n$).  But the (matrix-variate) moment generating function is also defined in the singular case, so you can use that result with some matrix algebra, and the result will fall out!

A key point in the calculations will be to write
$$
   (X_1-\bar{X}, \dots, X_n-\bar{X}) = A \begin{pmatrix} X \\ \bar{X} \end{pmatrix}
$$
with $A$ the $n \times (n+1) $-matrix (in block form)
$$
A=  \begin{pmatrix} I_n & -1_n \end{pmatrix}
$$
where $I_n$ is the identity matrix of size $n$, and $1_n$ is the $n$-vector (column) with all components equal to $1$.